# Cant align text right in android with react native

Tags: android, react-native

For some reason I'm unable to align text right in android using react native. My code works fine iOS, but not android does anyone know why or a fix?

Layout

```
<View style={styles.viewOC}>
         <Text style={styles.leftText}> Left</Text>
         <Text style={styles.rightText}> Right</Text>
  </View>
```

styles

```
...
  viewOC: {
    paddingTop: 8,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: "100%",
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    alignSelf:"stretch",
  },
  leftText: {
    textAlign: "left",
    fontSize: 12,
    justifyContent: "center",
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
  },
  rightText: {
    textAlign: "right",
    fontSize: 12,
    maxWidth: "50%",
    textAlignVertical: "top",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
  }...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using just these properties

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   
  viewOC: {
    paddingTop: 8,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",  
  },
  leftText: { 
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  rightText: { 
    fontSize: 12, 
  }
});
```